# Access Object send over self-made TFTP in python

Tags: python, sockets, memory, udp, tftp

I'm trying to create a TFTP in python over a existing UDP i have. In my server.py.

As of now I'm able to send requests to read (RRQ) and write (WRQ) to the server. However, then a Packet object (Created object to be sent over to the server) reaches the server, I'm unable to access it.

In server.py :

```
Packet =  (server_from_client.recv())
print Packet
print id(Packet)
print Packet.opCode
```

This produces this output :

```
('127.0.0.1', 53909)
recv done
<Packet.Packet object at 0x1e89f50>


42518000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "servertest.py", line 16, in <module>
print Packet.opCode
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'opCode'
```

Why does it first tell me that it's a Packet.Packet object (which does have an opCode) and then say it's a 'str' object with no opCode ????

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the code for the `Packet` class.

Comment: My guess is that your `print Packet` statement is what produces the empty lines before the id "42518000" - your recv method actually returns a string. But without seeing the rest of the code that is impossible to say, but obvisoulsy recv does print other stuff, so I guess it prints the <Packet.Packet..> thing too. BTW the address printed there 0x1e89f50 is different from the id 42518000 (0x288c5f0), so they are not the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending the packet, your client side converts it to the string `<Packet.Packet object at 0x1e89f50>` and sends it over the wire. Use `print type(Packet)` and `print repr(Packet)` to confirm.